# Android: Custom serialization json using gson library

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

I'm a beginner android developer, help deal with the serialization of the json response from the server

```
    {"resources": {"1": {"res-id": "11886", "duration": "00:30"},
                   "2": {"res-id": "13451", "duration": "00:30"},
                   "3": {"res-id": "13452", "duration": "00:30"},
                           .... end more items...}
```

(this is a real response from the server :() 
in object

```
   ArrayList <Resources> resources;
```

I ran into a problem, since objects are not nested array.
using gson library. 
google translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class:

```
public class ResourcesWrapper {
    @SerializedName("resources")
    private Map<String, Resources> mMapResources;

    public ArrayList<Resources> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Resources>(mMapResources.values());
    }

    public static class Resources {
        @SerializedName("res-id")
        private String mResId;
        @SerializedName("duration")
        private String mDuration;
    }
}
```

Then call GSON with:

```
new Gson().fromJson("{your_json}", ResourcesWrapper.class).getList()
```